# SQLite create and delete row when static data already exists in the List

Tags: android, sqlite

I am trying to impelement delete function with SQLite database. I have a list which already has some static data(Product_1,_2,_3...), then I add new positions with db.insert. Log say

```
05:35:10.875    495 example.CustomAdapter   DEBUG       row inserted, ID = 2
```

05:35:10.885    495 example.CustomAdapter   DEBUG       ID = 1, name = 
05:35:10.885    495 example.CustomAdapter   DEBUG       ID = 2, name = A1

Everything is OK new positions added and could be seen. Then I delete ID=1 with db.delete(DBHelper.TABLE, DBHelper.COLUMN_ID + id, null); (where id received from long id = acmi.id; AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo acmi = (AdapterView.AdapterContextMenuInfo) item.getMenuInfo();)and Log says no such column:

```
05:35:27.955    495 example.CustomAdapter   ERROR   AndroidRuntime  FATAL EXCEPTION: main
```

05:35:27.955    495 example.CustomAdapter   ERROR   AndroidRuntime  android.database.sqlite.SQLiteException: no such column: _id5: , while compiling: DELETE FROM mytable WHERE _id5
05:35:27.955    495 example.CustomAdapter   ERROR   AndroidRuntime      at android.database.sqlite.SQLiteCompiledSql.native_compile(Native Method)

What am I doing wrong? Could it be because I already have four positions filled with static data?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Please read this first:  http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Column_%28database%29

Then read this:

```
SQLiteException: no such column: _id5:
```

You do not have a column called _id5.  You have a column called ID which might contain the value 5.

To delete the row ([http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row_(database)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Row_%28database%29)) with the column ID containing 5:

```
db.delete(DBHelper.TABLE,"ID=" + id,null);
```

or

```
db.delete(DBHelper.TABLE,"ID=?",id);
```

where id is equal to 5.

Comment: Thanks, it works but how can I sinchronize delete from database and ArrayList<Product> product.remove(acmi.position) when it is actually deleted from screen. Is it possible or is not necessary to do this? Would it be messed up when I will try to delete static positions?

Comment: You're doing it the hard way, and the risky way, trying to keep a database and an arraylist in sync.  http://thinkandroid.wordpress.com/2010/01/09/simplecursoradapters-and-listviews/

Comment: It seems to me that when I call long id = acmi.id; I assign to database id = acmi.id and it it does not have anything incommen with actual database id? Am I correct?